# Querying Table containg millions of rows from Oracle database

Tags: performance, oracle, query-optimization, data-warehouse

I have a table finance (column : date,month,quarter,amount_usd,col1,col2,col3).

Simply querying ...

```
select sum(amount_usd) from finance
group by date
```

...takes 7 sec

```
select sum(amount_usd) from finance
group by month
```

...takes 6 sec

```
select sum(amount_usd) from finance
group by quarter
```

...takes 5 sec

So I have thought of Data Warehouse

I have created time dimention and hierarchy as

- date as child of month
- month as child of quarter

Now I am stuck...

What will be my fact table?
And how to query data from fact table?

This might be very basic question. But I am new to this.

Thanks

Comment: It is a big step from "my queries run slowly" to "I need a data warehouse". How many rows are "millions" and have you already tried to improve performance by using indexing, partitioned tables or other methods? A data warehouse would probably use very similar queries to the ones you have described, so you may need to be more specific about what you expect here.

Comment: The date column looks like it could be an ideal column to partition you data by.

Comment: @Pondlife... actually i wanted to know..how my dimensions help in performance...like i have created time dimention but when will i use it...Fact table can be my Finance table..or do i have to have separate one...and yes all indexing is there in table will have approxiamtly 1 million row....so my simple querys is taking time and thought of having Data warehouse concept....Thanks

Comment: @Avi 1 million rows is a small(ish) table for any modern database engine and it is almost certainly not worth building a data warehouse just for this. As APC has answered, you need to focus on tuning the queries (and perhaps system performance) rather than creating a whole new database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "so my simple querys is taking time and thought of having Data
>   warehouse concept..."

Seven seconds *is not slow*.  At least, not "need a data warehouse" slow.  A Data Warehouse is a strategic (usually enterprise level) environment, not a tuning technique.

However, I agree that it might be irritating for an OLTP user waiting for a screen to refresh.  What you need to do is *tune the query*.  You say you have indexes: but if you are summing the whole FINANCE table then you probably don't want to use indexes.  If you have an Enterprise Edition licence and multiple CPUs with spare capacity then parallel query might be a better idea.

If you run these finance queries many times a day you may derive some benefit from pre-aggregation but it seems unlikely that the reduction in elapsed time would justify the overhead of maintaining materialized views.